# Removing from List<> and Draw error

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

My problem is when I remove from the list my Draw function from the list is effected. unexpected file handling error

```
List<monster> Monster = new List<monster>();

//Initilize
Monster.add(new Monster());

//Update
if (Monster[0]. health == 0)
{
   Monster.removeAt[0];
}

//Draw

If (Monster[0].health > 0)
{
spriteBatch.Draw(Monster[0].texutre,Monster[0].pos,Color.White);
}
```

Is there a way to only draw the Monster depending on if there is one inside the List<>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code snippet for your drawing.

```
if(Monster.Any())
    spriteBatch.Draw(Monster.First().texutre,Monster.First().pos,Color.White);
```

This way it will draw a monster only if there is one. `Any()` and `First()` methods are LINQ so you have to specify `using System.Linq;` at the top of the .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

try looping in the list and add/remove tdhe monster

```
for(int i=0;i<Monster.Count(); i++)
{
 var m = Monster.ElementAt(i);
 //Update
if (m.health == 0)
{
   Monster.Remove(m)
}

//Draw

If (m.health > 0)
{
spriteBatch.Draw(m.texutre,m.pos,Color.White);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Monster.Count > 0){
    // draw
}
```